# Non-zero admissible representation of $sl_\infty$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Does someone has an example of a non-zero admissible representation of $sl_\infty$ ?

Comment: You mean Poisson Brackets? Like [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269389910575?via%3Dihub)?

Comment: By $sl_{\infty}$ I mean the Lie algebra defined by generators $X_i, Y_i, H_i$ with $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and commutators so that for $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ the sub Lie algebra generated by the $X_i, Y_i, H_i$ with $-N \leq i \leq N$ is isomorphic to $sl_{2(N+1)}$

Comment: [Poisson Brackets](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.528788).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found one.

We consider a vector space $V_m = \mathbb{C}V_0 \oplus \cdot\cdot\cdot \oplus \mathbb{C} V_m$ and the vector space $V^{(\mathbb{Z})}_n$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ indexed sequences of $V_m$ with a finite number of non zero terms.

Then, for $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ we introduce the basis $(v^i_p)$ where $0 \leq p \leq n$ and $-N \leq i \leq N$ of the subspace of $V^{(\mathbb{Z})}_n$ for which all terms vanish under $-N$ and above $N$. We define the action of the generators on that basis by :

$$X_iv^k_p = (n-p+1)\delta_{ik}v^k_{p-1}$$
$$Y_iv^k_p = (p+1)\delta_{ik}v^k_{p+1}$$
$$H_iv^k_p = (n-2p)\delta_{ik}v^k_p$$

We can see this satisfies $[X_i, Y_j] = \delta_{ij}H_j$ and similarly for $[H_i, X_j]$ and $[H_i, Y_j]$. Thus, this action defines a structure of representation of $sl_\infty$ on $V^{(\mathbb{Z})}_n$.

This representation is admissible and non zero by definitions of $V^{(\mathbb{Z})}_n$ and admissible representations.